# The use of the [dos] tag vs [denial-of-service]

Tags: discussion

I've started to go through and retag questions using [dos](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dos) and look at the question, and if it's genuinely about DOS, leave it.

If it's a denial of service, I've been retagging it as [denial-of-service](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/denial-of-service) because it's silly to have tags that are ambiguous for questions.

Comment: In a slightly unrelated note, we should work to get this to be the canonical answer for such things, so we can mark and close dupes http://serverfault.com/questions/99890/brainstorm-flood-dos-ddos-attack-prevention-ideas

Comment: Why, oh, why would anyone be asking about DOS (the OS) here?!

Comment: Is it safe to assume they mean MS-DOS? That way there can be no confusion...

Comment: I'm pretty sure they do.  I've been through every question tagged [dos], they're all either mistagged as denial of service, or relating to cmd on windoze.

Comment: @MarkHenderson For our purposes we can probably get away with saying "DOS is DOS", but they could easily be referring to FreeDOS (which is what I see popping up more and more in places where DOS is still a thing), or emulation (DOSBox, DOSEMU -- though those are probably worthy of their own tags)

Comment: Is there that much variance between freedos and msdos?

Comment: @TomO'Connor - I agree with your general sentiment but not quite so sure about that particular question, as the asker wishes to exclude third party s/w and/or tools from the Denial-of-service discussion. Not saying there's anything wrong with the question they're asking in itself, but I think a canonical question/answer has to include those alternatives.

Comment: @gWaldo: Legacy Applications... For example there are lots of ancient SCADA-like systems that only run on DOS. You'd be surprised to learn how many of these lurk in buildings doing things like controlling vents, lights, etc.

Comment: @kce Turbines, motors in nuclear fuel reprocessing plants. cf, stuxnet.

Comment: @TomO'Connor - the stuff of nightmares.

Answer (score 1):

This makes sense to me.

To answer @gWaldo's comment, DOS is still very much alive and kicking (and screaming, and doing all sorts of other horrible things).
I will admit to having software at $job running in a DOS emulator (until we can eliminate the last bits of our systems relying on it and make it go away), and it's also in some SCADA systems (which we as system administrators are sometimes tasked with interfacing with and monitoring.  I've had that pleasure...)

Comment: Insert sympathies here -->

Comment: In lieu of sympathy please send scotch.

Comment: NICE.  Shipping is expensive.  Tell you what: I'll keep a bottle here, and you can swing by for doses when needed...

Comment: Crap.  You're in NY; you might actually take me up on that...

Comment: Only if it's good scotch.

Comment: Well, I just got laid off a couple weeks ago, so no liquor for me in the meantime.  I'll probably celebrate with some Macallan when a new one is secured.